# Find a basis in which the form matrix is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Bilinear form $\phi$ defined on R³ has a matrix A in the canonical basis

A = $ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $

Find a basis in which the form matrix of $\phi$ is diagonal. How can I get started and what will be the answer? Please help

Comment: What is the context and what did you attempted?

Comment: I think the answer will be XAX^T=B but i dont know, how to find X, and is there any catch?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: But the problem is that this is all I know, this is whole homework I get from my professor. I just need to find basis

Comment: Hint : permute the canonical basis.

Answer (score 1):

Currently under this transformation, if $x = [x_1,x_2,x_3]^T$ then $Ax = [x_3,x_2,x_1]^T$. So it is switching the first and third coordinates of the vector.

If this transformation has a $3$ linearly independent eigenvectors then they will form a basis so that $A$ is diagonalizable. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ (which I leave for you to verify) is $-(\lambda - 1)^2(\lambda + 1)$ so the eigenvalues are $\lambda = -1$ and $1$ (with multiplicity $2$).

Then you can find eigenvectors $v$ by finding a $v$ such that $(A - \lambda I)v = 0$. I'll leave this for you to do, but you should get the eigenvectors $v_1 = [1,0,1]^T$ and $v_2 = [0,1,0]^T$ for $\lambda = 1$ and $v_3 = [1,0,-1]^T$ for $\lambda = -1$.

Now if we apply our transformation then $\phi(v_1) = v_1, \phi(v_2) = v_2, \phi(v_3) = -v_3$. So the corresponding matrix with respect to the basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ which is diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

This begins with a special case in the algorithm I, well, promote. I like to call the symmetric matrix $H$   for "Hessian" then the outcome is called $D.$  If the quadratic form has rational coefficients then all of it comes out rational.  When it is demanded that all entries of $D$   come out as $(1,0,-1),  \; \; $ you may then apply a new $E_j$  which is diagonal, all entries of the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|D_{ii}|}}$  when $D_{ii}$ is nonzero.

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Here is information and how you do it, with the individual matrices accomplishing each step:

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$